# Удаление папки со всем содержимым в цикле

Tags: linux, bash

Стоит задача: читать построчно файл и удалять папки на сервере, путь к которым соответсвует строка из читаемого файла.

Я написал цикл

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/clean.lst"
/bin/mv -f $file $file.tmp
while IFS= read -r line
do
    /bin/rm -rf "$line"
done <"$file.tmp"
/bin/rm $file.tmp
```

Однако внутри цикла папка не удаляется. Хотя если напрямую в консоле набрать 
`/bin/rm -rf /home/folder/`, то все удалаляется нормально.

Что не так в цикле?

Comment: *Что не так в цикле?* - Насколько я понял, всё "так". Я протестировал Ваш скрипт - он работает.  И внутри папки всё удаляется и сама папка удаляется и временный файл тоже удаляется.  Проверьте два момента: 1) В файле *clean.lst* файлы заданы с полным путём? Или они доступны из рабочей директории, в которой запускается скрипт? 2) В момент запуска скрипта - достаточно прав на удаление этих файлов?

Answer (score 1):

Что у вас в file.tmp, возможно пуст.

Если оболочка bash - однострочник вам поможет:

```
~$ < list_of_paths xargs -I% rm -rfv %
```

Если читаете из переменной в цикле `while` -  используйте `<<< $file.tmp` в ином случае читайте напрямую файла `< clean.lst`

Comment: Файл $filte.tmp точно содержит строку. А далее я смотрел дату создания папки, которую должен был цикл удалить, и она оказывалась старой, т.е. папка не была удалена. И это было конечно странно ;)